# Uniform (Sobolev-esque) norm involving all derivatives of smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm trying to construct a norm on the space $\mathcal{D}(\Omega) := \{ f \in C^\infty(\Omega) | f $ is compactly supported on $ \Omega \}$ where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. I want this norm to include, somehow, the $L^\infty$-norms of **all** the derivatives of the smooth function to which it is applied. Specifically, I want to be able to encapsulate the statement

"*$f_n$$^{(m)} \rightarrow f^{(m)} ($as $n \rightarrow \infty)$ uniformly for all non-negative values of $m$.*"

as the statement

"$\|f_n - f\| \rightarrow 0$ $(n \rightarrow \infty)$.",

where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes my desired norm.

So far I've considered trying to write it as something along the lines of

\begin{align}\|f\| := \sum\limits_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{m!} \|f^{(m)}\|_\infty, \end{align}
where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denotes the usual $L^\infty$-norm. I am very unsure of the validity of this sort of "definition", as I can't see how to prove that this (or a related/similar) series converges. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically, $C^\infty(\Omega)$ contains unbounded functions. So you can only use $L^\infty$ norms on a (rather small) subspace of that.

Comment: You cannot go very far without requesting some boundedness assumption on $f$ and its derivatives.

Comment: Alternatively, you can define a "local" version of your topology, by weakening the notion of convergence so that it is uniform only on compact subsets of $\Omega$.

Comment: However, $C^\infty(\Omega)$ is a fine Fréchet space with the topology of compact convergence in all derivatives.

Comment: Side note: The comments by me and those by Daniel Fischer are saying exactly the same thing.

Comment: I have edited the question slightly. It now matches the structure as given in Numerical Models for Differential Problems, A. Quarteroni, although it is a specific case of the definition he gave (which was for multi-index partial differentiation in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Does the fact the functions have compact support aid in the construction of such a norm? Forgive me if this should be obvious, but I'm still quite new to the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in functional analysis, but I think this answers your question.

The topology of $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is not induced by a norm. There is a discussion of this in chapter 1 of Rudin's Functional Analysis book. Briefly, a topological vector space whose topology is induced by a norm is locally bounded (proof: the open unit ball is bounded). So we want to show that $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is not locally bounded. There is a result stating that a locally bounded topological vector space satisfying the Heine-Borel property (every closed and bounded set is compact) is finite-dimensional. So it only remains to show the Heine-Borel property for either $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ or $C^\infty(\Omega)$.

If you like, I can provide more details from Rudin's book.

Comment: I have not assumed any topology on $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$. It is simply the vector space of all continuous, real-valued functions on $\Omega$ which have compact support. Also, I'm not sure in what way your ideas help in constructing a norm with the desired property that: a function sequence has that every sequence, of derivatives of its terms of a fixed order ($m$), is uniformly convergent in $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ if and only if it is convergent under the topology of this norm.

Comment: In a metric space (which a normed vector space certainly is), specifying the limits of sequences determines a topology, so you are implicitly assuming a topology on $\mathcal{D}(\Omega).$ Moreover, even if you *were* only assuming a vector space structure, then the problem is trivial since every infinite dimensional vector space admits some norm. To be clear, what I'm saying is that a norm of the type you're looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: What if the space is restricted somewhat, e.g., consider only sequences of functions from the space $L^\infty (\Omega) \cap \mathcal{D} (\Omega)$?

Comment: Don't take my word for it, but I think the same argument should apply. In particular I think $L^\infty(\Omega)\cap\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ should still satisfy the Heine-Borel property, since both $L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ do (I think).

Comment: A minor note: when one writes the symbol $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ it usually denotes the space of continuous functions with compact support equipped with a topology whose induced notion of convergence is 
$$u_n \to u\ \iff\ \forall D\subset\subset \Omega,\ \forall \alpha\in \mathbb{N},\ \sup_{x\in D}\lvert \partial^\alpha u_n(x)-\partial^\alpha u(x)\rvert\to 0.$$

Comment: Where $D\subset \subset \Omega$ means that $D$ is a bounded open set whose closure is in $\Omega$. I wrote all this to point out that this topology does not come from any *metric* (one says that it is *not metrizable*), let alone from a norm.

Comment: I proved today that $\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \subset L^\infty(\Omega) \cap L^2 (\Omega)$. Still struggling to make it work. I need to show that for any $f \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$, there exists $M>0$ such that $\|f^{(n)}\|_\infty<M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\Omega$ is open then there is no norm on $C^\infty(\Omega)$, it is a classical Montel space.

In addition, for compact $K\subset\Omega$ we may put $\sup_{x\in K}|f^{(k)}(x)|$ is finite, but $\sup_K\sup_{x\in K}|f^{(k)}(x)|$ may be infinite.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have edited the question, now. Does this help in construction of the norm?

Comment: $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is also a Montel space. You can read about in Hörmander "An introduction to the theory of linear  partial differential operators Vol I" or Rudin "Functional Analysis".